# Spring MVC - date issue

Tags: json, spring-mvc

Backend Spring MVC and Hibernate. Front end Angularjs. The database I am using is DB2.

Problem: the data field in my JSON object is returning under the form of a random integer ("startDate":1450828800000). The actual date in the DB is "2015-12-23".
The data type for this column in the db is set to DATE.

My code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PURCHASEORDER",schema = "POTOOL")
public class PurchaseOrder {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    private Date startDate;

    //rest of the code, including getter and setters
```

Answer (score 0):

What you see in your JSON response is not a random integer, rather your DB value converted to milliseconds. You can annotate your Date with the following annotation to have the same representation as inside a DB

```
 @JsonFormat(shape= JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
 private Date startDate;
```

The annotations belong to `jackson-annotation.jar` if you're using maven you can add the following dependency and it will pull the annotations jar transitively

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

if you're not using maven you can still download the jars from maven repo, or find the equivalent conf for your build, hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for that. Any idea which is the library which will allow me to import this. I did a search on google but is pretty confusing.

Comment: Salve Thanks for that. I am actually using maven, I've added the dependency but no change on the front end. I don't know if this prob is related to the DB2 as its the firs time I am using this db. With my SQL never had a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I can format the date with Angularjs like this:  {{po.startDate |date:"yyyy-MM-dd" }}

Still confused why the on the JSON response the date is not converted...